# redirect with php buttons in existing item-post.php

Tags: php

```
 <div class="row">
          <label for="AdsType"><?php _e('Ads Type', 'modern'); ?></label>
           <select  id="AdsType" name="AdsType"  >
                    <option>Standard</option>
                     <option>Premium</option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

once user selects Standard button I want it to be redirected to www.site.com/complete.php
once user selects Premium button I want it to be redirected to www.site.com/pay.php

What is the extra coding I add in my existing php file before:

```
<button  type="submit"><?php _e('Publish', 'modern'); ?></button>
```

Comment: Hi, as there are only two options in your dropdown, the "Standard" will be already selected. Do you want to redirect user when the select the option or when they select and then submit the form?

Comment: when they submit the form :)

Comment: If you are okay to consider Javascript, try http://api.jquery.com/submit/#example-0. Changing the text element to your required select element.

Answer (score 0):

You can change action url which is in the form using javascript

```
// call to change_action() function onChange event
<select  id="AdsType" name="AdsType" onChange="change_action();" >
    <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
    <option value="Premium">Premium</option>
</select>


// change action url
<script language="javascript">
function change_action()
{
    if(document.getElementById("AdsType").value=="Standard")
    {
        form_name.action="www.site.com/complete.php";   
    }
    else
    {
        form_name.action="www.site.com/pay.php";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: ok where would I paste the javascript stuff? in the same php as the select id adstype?